# why is "conda create env" killed?

Tags: conda

I am trying to create a conda environment in win10-ubuntu subsystem using the following command:

```
conda env create -f ../single-cell-tutorial-master/sc_tutorial_environment.yml
```

but the process is always killed at environment solving. The output reads as:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / Killed
```

During the process is running, the computer memory is occupied up to 98%. The memory of my computer is 16 G, which I though is not small.
So is the "create env" killed because the memory is not enough? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Not enough info. Can you share the YAML? We may be able to help recommend changes. Factors that can impact solution space size are 1) heterogeneity (e.g., mixing R and Python); 2) specificity (e.g., not specifying Python version through minor). Also, use Mamba instead of Conda.

Comment: The YAML can be downloaded here: https://github.com/theislab/single-cell-tutorial/blob/master/sc_tutorial_environment.yml

Comment: Ugh, that's a nasty YAML - no wonder it blew up for you. It should be spilt into at least three separate environments: 1) Jupyter infrastructure (just `jupyter` and `nb_conda_kernels`); 2) a Python kernel (`python=3.9`, `ipykernel`, and all the other Python packages, including `pip` stuff, most of which is now on Conda); 3) an R kernel (`r-base=4.2`, `r-irkernel`, `r-reticulate`). Also, versions need updating - no one should use Python <3.8 for new projects, and Bioconductor evolves quickly (hence the R 4.2).

Comment: There is no "nb_conda_kernels",  "r-base=4.2", "r-irkernel", and "r-reticulate" in the list. Should I add them when I separate the yaml file?

Comment: Yes, I recommend these additional packages because they enable loading separate environments in Jupyter very simple.

Comment: I try to create the first env containing only jupyter and nb_conda_kernels, but get the following error: An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Comment: and you have a linux-64 version of Conda installed in WSL2?

Comment: Yes. That's right. I just ran the following command to install WSL2 in powershell of 64 version win 10: wsl --install -d ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the yaml file. The problem is the amount of RAM required.At least make sure you have 8GB(or More if required) of FREE RAM when running the model. I switched from 4GB RAM(the 3.9GB RAM AND 1 GB Swap) to 16GB. I later changed the mem value to 12 GB in the wsl2 config as show by this [article](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/08/31/windows-en-wsl-2-memory/) and everything worked fine.

Comment: Was having issues when trying to install on a cluster and had only reserved a single core. The memory that is then allocated automatically alongt his single core was not enough to execute the installation. Kind of strange to me that this step is so resource intensive though.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem recently. I am in China, and there is a problem in using conda for a series of reasons. My solution is to use mamba(a package to replace the conda, faster and more useful), almost all package you can use mamba

Comment: When leaving an answer, please make sure that you actually answer the question posted. This was a very specific question and not about replacing conda.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup as yours and also encountered the same issue. Increasing the swap space (I set mine to 20GB) resolved the environment creation for me.